# Starting tips on how to benchmark any repository on GitHub using Airspeed Velocity

Tags: python, performance, oop, github, benchmarking

I am new to airspeed velocity and I want to benchmark a repository on GitHub using asv.

So can you give me starting guidelines on how can I benchmark this repo or any repo, also can you tell me some good benchmarks (Python functions) that should be run on the repo? I have installed asv and I have ran all sample default benchmarks, but I want to write some custom benchmarks so how do I start and what are some general benchmarks?

Comment: Without any concrete example of what you did, how can anyone give you a better answer than "read the documentation". What you are basically saying is something like "I need to know more about ASV, and I'm hoping somebody here can guess what I need to know and tell me that". IMHO, only masochists will take up such a challenge.

Comment: What are some standard benchmark functions in python that I can write for a repository? for reference can you guide me upon what type of benchmarks can I write for https://github.com/GTron-1729/einsteinpy. This is my forked version, please guide me upon benchmarks on it. @AmitaiIrron

Answer (score 1):

The benchmarks you write depend on the software you want to test. If you just already use the software in your projects, you will know typical workflows that may be worth testing.

If you have never used the software, I would suggest to start with modified versions of the unit tests that come with the software. Unit tests are often designed to run quickly, so they work with minimal data and small examples.

You should still be able to adapt them, or get ideas, for your performance tests. Other documentation of the software, like tutorials, may also include typical workflows -- maybe even with example data that is a bit more realistic than what is used in the unit tests.